# Error al declarar un query nativo usando el metodo @Query - Spring JPA data

Tags: java, api, spring, spring-boot, jpa

He estado trabajando con angular y java en una apirest. Cuando implemento el metodo @Query:

```
@Query("select e from Empleado e where e.nombre like %?1%")
public List<Empleado> findByNombre (String term1);
```

**El método anterior funciona correctamente** cuando estoy haciendo una busqueda del nombre en el front. Cuando deseo implementar un método nativo de query el cual es:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT nombre FROM empleados AS e WHERE e.nombre like %?1%", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Empleado> findByNombreMetodoDos (String term1);
```

este ultimo método no genera error al compilar pero cuando estoy en el front empiezo a escribir **en la busqueda el nombre genera el error, este es el error**:

```
2020-06-07 11:41:03.609  WARN 10452 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2020-06-07 11:41:03.609 ERROR 10452 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'id_empleado' not found.
2020-06-07 11:41:03.612 ERROR 10452 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT nombre FROM empleados AS e WHERE e.nombre = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
```

Este es el modelo entidad - no agrego el resto de código (otros atributos y getter y setters):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="empleados")
public class Empleado implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_empleado")
    private Integer idEmpleado;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotEmpty(message = "no puede estar vacio.")
    @Size(min=3, max=50, message = "debe tener un tamaño entre 3 y 50 caracteres")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotEmpty(message = "no puede estar vacio")
    private String apellido;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="empleados_roles", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empleado_Id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="rol_Id"),
    uniqueConstraints= {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"empleado_Id", "rol_Id"})})
    private List<Rol> roles;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el aplication.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_consultorio
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456789
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect

spring.jackson.time-zone=America/Bogota
spring.jackson.locale=es_CO

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

Nota: otros métodos CRUD funcionan correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es una proyección, pero no puedes hacerlo directamente en JPA, porque los métodos del repositorio retornan o bien una entidad del tipo que le especificaste, o bien una colección de ellos (de ahí el error que no encuentra id_empleado, porque intenta encontrar todas las propiedades para construir un objecto Empleado).

Lo que tienes que hacer es definir una interface para cada proyección distinta que necesites, con los datos que necesites:

```
public interface EmpleadoNombre {
    String getNombre();
}
```

Luego tu repositorio:

```
@Repository
public interface EmpleadoRepository extends JpaRepository<Empleado, Integer> {

    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM empleado e WHERE e.nombre like %?1%", nativeQuery="true")
    <T> List<T> obtenerNombres(String nombre, Class<T> type);
}
```

y luego, lo puedes llamar así:

```
@Autowired
EmpleadoRepository empleadoRepository;
...
List<EmpleadoNombre> nombres = empleadoRepository.obtenerNombres(EmpleadoNombre.class);
```

Puedes agregar más parámetros a tu query si quieres filtrar por algún atributo, pero el último parámetro tiene que ser el tipo (interface) que retornará tu proyección.

Comment: Hola Alex es decir que: List<EmpleadoNombre> nombres = obtenerNombres(EmpleadoNombre.class);      debo llamarlo directamente al controlador? o en uno de los servicios de IEmpleadoService? como debería hacer ese llamado o en donde exactamente?

Comment: Perdón, edité la respuesta porque había olvidado la instancia del repositorio.
En realidad lo llamas desde donde prefieras, si tienes una capa de servicios, pues del servicio, si no, puedes llamarlo desde el controlador. Igual que cuando usas findByNombre(), que sí te funciona. Solo recuerda que debes inyectar el repositorio donde sea que lo vayas a usar.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Una cosa más, puedes agregar más interfaces con las propiedades que necesites, y luego puedes reusar el mismo método simplemente pasándole el tipo de la interface que necesitas como último parámetro.